Count the values in two different books in power query
I have two different books, one is fruit and other result.
result book contains unique values of fruit book as mentioned below
result book : https://i.sstatic.net/Lh0m37td.png
fruit book
: https://i.sstatic.net/6HYQa6ZB.png
I want to count of all the fruits which are completed and UT in fruits book.
conditions : status = completed and ut/un = ut.
I want to get the output in result book

I tried the below logic but somewhere I'm missing it.
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="result"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"fruit", type text}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "completed", each "completed"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "ut-completed", each List.Count( Table.SelectRows(#"fruit1", (ft1) => ft1[fruits] = [fruit] and ft1[status] = [completed] ))) in  #"Added Custom"

Thank you.

you can try below formula.
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "result", each List.Count(Table.SelectRows( fruit1, (ft) => ft[fruits] = [fruit] and ft[unut] = [utt]  and ft[status] = [cmpl])[unut]))

Note: I have changed un/ut column as unut in fruit1 book.

